# OpenStreetMap - How to use the downloadable database?

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap

I've download the data of three countries (The Netherlands, Belgium and Germany) (e.g https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/netherlands.html) and I'd like to use those to populate my OSM with (street names, addresses etc.). 
However after extensive searching I haven't managed to find not one clear example on how to use it properly.

My use case; using the downloadable OSM database to populate a OSM in JavaScript. (Using https://leafletjs.com/)

The database file I use is .pbf

Does anyone know how to use this database format to populate my OpenStreetMap?

Thanks in advance

Comment: PBF is raw data whereas leaflet usually expects rendered tiles. Why don't you use one of the existing tile servers? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to populate your map using the data you've gathered. To do this, first, you'll have to arrange it in an ordered way, recognizable by the server/backend or a program that'll understand users request and return appropriate data.

To do this you'll need to parse the data.
In python one way to do this is given in this link: [imposm.parser - OpenStreetMap XML/PBF parser for Python](https://imposm.org/docs/imposm.parser/latest/)

After this, you'll have to set up entry points to your server that'll understand the users request and return appropriate data. This can be done using Flask (python). Links: [Flask - Official documentation (Quickstart)](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/) or [Flask Mega tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)

Then, finally, you'll have to create the entry point for users i.e. your web page which will consist of the map. You could use leaflet.js or [google maps for developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/) (I prefer the latter)

Now, your project has various parameters that are undefined i.e. the programming language (I have provided links with respect to python programming language, but you can use nodejs or any other according to your convenience). Whether it is for public use or private and similarly many more parameters. Hence it is quite an open question. Regardless, you'll have to follow the steps as listed above...

Thanks!

Comment: Is there also a way to use it without having to manually parse it through python and run it over a python server? Like using the .pbf directly in JavaScript

Comment: Not that I know of... But the easiest it could get should be by using NodeJS. you'll be hosting a "local server" but it is entire javascript. Pretty easy!